# JSON generic collection deserialization

Tags: java, json, spring, deserialization, generic-collections

I've such DTO classes written in Java:

```
public class AnswersDto {
    private String uuid;
    private Set<AnswerDto> answers;
}

public class AnswerDto<T> {
    private String uuid;
    private AnswerType type;
    private T value;
}

class LocationAnswerDto extends AnswerDto<Location> {
}

class JobTitleAnswerDto extends AnswerDto<JobTitle> {
}

public enum AnswerType {
    LOCATION,
    JOB_TITLE,
}

class Location {
    String text;
    String placeId;
}

class JobTitle {
    String id;
    String name;
}
```

In my project there is Jackson library used for serialization and deserialization of JSONs.

How to configure `AnswersDto` (use special annotations) or `AnswerDto` (annotation as well) classes to be able to properly deserialize request with `AnswersDto` in its body, e.g.:

```
{
    "uuid": "e82544ac-1cc7-4dbb-bd1d-bdbfe33dee73",
    "answers": [
        {
            "uuid": "e82544ac-1cc7-4dbb-bd1d-bdbfe33dee73",
            "type": "LOCATION",
            "value": {
                "text": "Dublin",
                "placeId": "121"
            }
        },
        {
            "uuid": "e82544ac-1cc7-4dbb-bd1d-bdbfe33dee73",
            "type": "JOB_TITLE",
            "value": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Developer"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately Jackson by default maps value of `AnswerDto` object to `LinkedHashMap` instead of object of proper (`Location` or `JobTitle`) class type.
Should I write custom `JsonDeserializer<AnswerDto>` or configuration by use of `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` could be enough?

To properly deserialize request with just one `AnswerDto` in form of

```
{
    "uuid": "e82544ac-1cc7-4dbb-bd1d-bdbfe33dee73",
    "type": "LOCATION",
    "value": {
        "text": "Dublin",
        "placeId": "121"
    }
}
```

I'm using:

```
AnswerDto<Location> answerDto = objectMapper.readValue(jsonRequest, new TypeReference<AnswerDto<Location>>() {
});
```

without any other custom configuration.

Comment: You have a collection of aswer objects but you want to deserialize to only one answer object ? What about using AnswersDto answers = objectMapper.readValue(jsonRequest, new TypeReference<AnswersDto>() {});

Comment: I want to map all objects from `answers` node to `Set<AnswerDto>` collection.
When I use `objectMapper` with this `TypeReference<AnswersDto>` than unfortunately `value` property of every `AnswerDto` from collection is mapped to `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've resolved issue by using Jackson's custom annotations `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes`:

```
public class AnswerDto<T> {

    private String uuid;

    private AnswerType type;

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Location.class, name = AnswerType.Types.LOCATION),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = JobTitle.class, name = AnswerType.Types.JOB_TITLE)
    })
    private T value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to make a separate interface for possible answer values and use [`@JsonTypeInfo`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html) on it. You can also drop `type` field from `AnswerDto`, `AnswerType` enum, and additional `*AnswerDto` classes becuse jackson will add type info for you. Like this

```
public class AnswerDto<T extends AnswerValue> {
    private String uuid;
    private T value;
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY)
interface AnswerValue {}

class Location implements AnswerValue { /*..*/ }
class JobTitle implements AnswerValue { /*..*/ }
```

Resulting json will looks like this

```
{
  "uuid": "e82544ac-1cc7-4dbb-bd1d-bdbfe33dee73",
  "answers": [
    {
      "uuid": "e82544ac-1cc7-4dbb-bd1d-bdbfe33dee73",
      "value": {
        "@class": "com.demo.Location",
        "text": "Dublin",
        "placeId": "121"
      }
    },
    {
      "uuid": "e82544ac-1cc7-4dbb-bd1d-bdbfe33dee73",
      "value": {
        "@class": "com.demo.JobTitle",
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Developer"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Which will be parsed using

```
AnswersDto answersDto = objectMapper.readValue(json, AnswersDto.class);
```

But this solution applies only in cases when you are a producer of json data and you do not have to think about backward compatibility.

In other cases you'll have to make custom desetializer for `AnswersDto` class.