# How to handle that json response in java?

Tags: java, json, rest, web, service

I have created a rest web service and a client. Client is calling a function to get all playlists. Service is returning a List of objects(Playlist). How to save this response on a client?

Resource class:

```
@GET
public List<Playlist> getAllPlaylists(){
    return playlistservice.getAllPlaylists();
}
```

Service class:

```
    public List<Playlist> getAllPlaylists(){
    return new ArrayList<Playlist>(playlists.values());
}
```

Client code(im getting error here)

```
List<Playlist> a = new ArrayList<Playlist>();

                        a = playlistsTarget
                                .request()
                                .get(List<Playlist>.class); // error here
```

How to save this response to List of playlist?

Comment: Please show understandable client code with a bit more context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON generic collection deserialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273998/json-generic-collection-deserialization)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the fix.
I changed from: `.get(List<Playlist>.class);`
to: `.get(new GenericType<List<Playlist>>() {});`

I found the fix on youtube here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxDFpVLUDFY&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTY40IcG584ynNqibMc1heIa&index=19